# Handle Click Button in recycler view

Tags: android, button, android-recyclerview

I have recycler view with OnItemTouchListener and each row this recycler has a button with onclick event.

I want after click button event work but OnItemTouchListener work.

please help. my code.

```
public class RecyclerViewTouchListener  implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {


private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private ClickListener clickListener;

public RecyclerViewTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clickListener=clickListener;
    gestureDetector=new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child!=null && clickListener!=null){
                clickListener.OnClick(child,recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        //noinspection deprecation
        clickListener.OnClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}


public static interface ClickListener {
    void OnClick(View view,int position);

}
```

}

this code in viewholder

```
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            callbacks.removePosition(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });
```

Comment: *I want after click button event work but OnItemTouchListener work.* what?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: @TimCastelijns                                excuse me. I want after click button, on click method run.  but onclick method button dont work and only onItemTouchListener run.

Comment: Return `true` from `onInterceptTouchEvent` instead of false..!!

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for my straightness, but first of all delete this code. Then you need to create your own RecyclerAdapter that will have such snippet of code:

```
View.OnClickListener clickListener;

public void setOnItemClickListener(View.OnClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}

@Override
public final void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (onClickListener != null) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    }
}
```

Then somewhere where you work with RecyclerView (Activity, Fragment, custom View, custom Wrapper for View) you should do something like that:

```
List<SomeItem> someItems = getSomeItems();//Receive items for adapter from some place
MyRecyclerAdapter adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(someItems);
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = orderListView.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
            SomeItem item = someItems.get(position);
            Log.v("CLICKED", "Clicking on item(" + position + ", " + item + ")");
        }
    });
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Next to your question about clicking on buttons inside any item.
Define your own Holder that keeps references for View components inside you item:

```
public static class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final Button deleteButton;

    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        deleteButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
    }

    public Button getDeleteButton() {
        return deleteButton;
    }
}
```

Then define your own inteface for define clicks on delete button. For example:

```
public interface OnDeleteButtonItemClickListener {
    void onDeleteIsClick(View button, int position); 
}
```

Then attach your interface to Adapter:

```
View.OnClickListener clickListener;
OnDeleteButtonItemClickListener deleteButtonListener;

public void setOnItemClickListener(View.OnClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}

public void setDeleteButtonListener(OnDeleteButtonItemClickListener  deleteButtonListener) {
    this.deleteButtonListener= deleteButtonListener;
}

@Override
public final void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (clickListener!= null) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    }

    if (deleteButtonListener!= null) {
        MyHolder myHolder = (MyHolder) holder;
        myHolder.getDeleteButton().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            deleteButtonListener.onDeleteIsClick(v, position)
        }
    });;
    }
}
```

And then update your place, where you work with RecyclerView:

```
List<SomeItem> someItems = getSomeItems();//Receive items for adapter from some place
MyRecyclerAdapter adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(someItems);
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = orderListView.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
            SomeItem item = someItems.get(position);
            Log.v("CLICKED", "Clicking on item(" + position + ", " + item + ")");
        }
    });
adapter.setDeleteButtonListener(new OnDeleteButtonItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onDeleteIsClick(View button, int position) {
            SomeItem item = someItems.get(position);
            Log.v("CLICKED", "Clicking on delete button of item(" + position + ", " + item + ")");
        }
});
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Asking a question after two years, so please pardon me. You mention : Then define your own inteface for define clicks on delete button. Where is this interface to be defined? In the Activity or the Adapter?

Comment: @kilokahn I think it is more the matter of a taste. I prefer to put it in adapter since it is a place where the work with instance of that interface is happened. 

But for example, this interface can be used in a several different adapters. In that case I would have an file with bunch of such common click interfaces